# onbeforeunload - Can I get the reason of invocation? I want to identify a redirect

Tags: javascript, angularjs, redirect, onbeforeunload

I need to pop-up a 'verify save' message using the onbeforeunload event (when the user closes the window or clicks a link that 'leaves' my Angular app page).

That works great, but I realized that when I get a 302 redirect, the event fires as well.
Now I understand that I'm before unloading the page, but I don't want it to run when I get redirected.

How can I detect a redirection on the event?

```
$window.onbeforeunload = function (event) {
       // how can I identify if this event was invoked due to a redirect?    
       return "If you leave the page now your changes won't be saved.";
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you can use the state of the document? Has the window onload event happened when a 302 occur? Or could you use document.readyState?

Comment: How do you get the `302` redirect exactly? Is it sent from the same domain as your angular app?